# How to define different list items background images in react native?

Tags: react-native

In my app, I want different cards have different background images, every image has a number text, and when I click the image it can increase the number by one. now I have them with same image background image, I do not know how to modify my code to meet this requirement. The following is my code:

```
const MyMeetupsList = ({meetups}) => (
    <FlatList
      data={meetups}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={{marginLeft:8, marginTop: 8} }>
          <View style={styles.meetupCard}>
            <ImageBackground source={ require('../../../imgs/food-2.jpg')} style={{width: 175, height: 200}} blurRadius={6}>
              <Text style={styles.gridItemText}>{item.title}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
      numColumns={2}
      keyExtractor={item => item.title}
    />
);
```

Hope you can help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute extraData for tracking any change to the dataset and flatlist will rerender on any changes applied on data set. Here i added Map data set( Immutable.js) which can be used to track multiple data sets. If you have only one then you can put that data set straight away. handleClickAction is a function u need to define to mutate your data.

```
 const MyMeetupsList = ({meetups}) => (
        <FlatList
          data={meetups} 
           extraData={Map({
            foo: meetups, // here you can put any data sets u want to watch for render

           })}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={{marginLeft:8, marginTop: 8} }>
              <View style={styles.meetupCard}>
                <ImageBackground source={ require('../../../imgs/food-2.jpg')} style={{width: 175, height: 200}} blurRadius={6} 
           onPress = {()=>handleClickAction(item.id)} >
                      <Text style={styles.gridItemText}>{item.title}</Text>
                    </ImageBackground>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
              numColumns={2}
              keyExtractor={item => item.title}
            />
        );
```

I hope above snippet helps